# Перевести bitmap в drawable

Tags: android, java, canvas, bitmap

Нужно решить следующую задачу: есть listview в каждом пункте есть кружочек - маркер, который должен быть в каждом итеме разного цвета, каналы RGB записаны в трех массивах. Сначала пробовал обойтись без картинки: просто создавал канву, рисовал, конвертировал в bitmap, a ее в свою очереди в drawable, но эта попытка не принесла никакого результата, вот что пишут логи:

```
06-04 16:05:10.978: E/BitmapFactory(1233): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@527e700c: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

далее пробовал так: закинул png с рисунком круга, переводил ее в массив пикселов, и в цикле изменял каждый пиксель, ничего не вышло, та же ошибка. ниже фрагмент кода

```
//LIST VIEW
        lvdata = (ListView)rootView2.findViewById(R.id.lv_graph);
        lvdata.setDivider(null);
        lvdata.setClickable(false);
        lvdata.setFocusable(false);

        circle = (ImageView)rootView2.findViewById(R.id.graph_ing);

        name = (TextView)rootView2.findViewById(R.id.graph_lv_name);
        procent = (TextView)rootView2.findViewById(R.id.graph_lv_procent);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(
                names.length);
        HashMap<String, Object> map;

        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;
        int r = 4;

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();

        /*Bitmap bmOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.circle);*/

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            mPaint.setColor(0xFF0000);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            mCanvas.drawCircle(x,y,r,mPaint);

            BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("Name", names[i]);
            map.put("Proccent", procents100[i]+"%");
            map.put("Icon", drawable);
            data.add(map);
        }

        String[] from = { "Name", "Proccent", "Icon" };

        int[] to = { R.id.graph_lv_name, R.id.graph_lv_procent, R.id.graph_ing };

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.item2,
                from, to);

        lvdata.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView2;
    }
```

Comment: А в манифесте у вас прописано разрешение на доступ к памяти? Может в этом дело.

Comment: Как только проверю, тут же отмечу)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > 06-04 16:05:10.978: E/BitmapFactory(1233): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: **/android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@527e700c**: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Как видно из вышеприведённого, `SimpleAdapter` пытается прочитать и декодировать посредством `BitmapFactory` файл по адресу `/android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@527e700c`, и, естественно, его там не находит. Как не сложно догадаться, `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@527e700c` — есть ни что иное, как результат `drawable.toString()`.

Причина сего поведения проста, и объяснение ему содержится, как ни странно, в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html):

> the following views are then tried in order:
>
> - A view that implements Checkable (e.g. CheckBox). The expected bind value is a boolean.
> - TextView. The expected bind value is a string and setViewText(TextView, String) is invoked.
> - ImageView. The **expected bind value is a resource id or a string** and setViewImage(ImageView, int) or setViewImage(ImageView, String) is invoked.

Обратите внимание на выделенную часть. Из неё следует, что для `ImageView` `SimpleAdapter` ожидает либо `int`, либо `String`, интерпретируя их как `resource id` или `file path` соответственно. Вы же помещаете в `map` экземпляр `Drawable`.

Правильный выход из этой ситуации — не использовать `SimpleAdapter`, а наследовать свой адаптер непосредственно от `BaseAdapter`, имплементируя нужные методы.